# Windows Phone 8.1 - Access media libraries deep/recursive queries

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application and I need fast/efficient access to the media files on the device. I have been following the [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx) and my difficulty is 2-fold:

1. According to the Documentation, I should be able to deep-query the Videos library, ordering files by date, e.g. I believe this call should work but it does not:

   await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);

it causes this exception to be thrown:

{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.   at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery query)

However, a similar query on the Pictures library does work. The only way I can get it to work for Videos is to specify "OrderByName" rather than Date, but this is not what I need!

2. It seems that queries on the VideosLibrary does not include the Camera roll. This is a problem because videos taken by the device camera are typically saved to the camera roll folder and not to the "Videos" folder. Therefore in order to find videos captured by the device I have to implement my own recursive search of the Camera roll.

I'd be grateful for any tips anybody has who has encountered these issues.

Thanks
Joe.

Comment: What Integer value does CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate evaluate to if you debug?

Comment: Hi there - it evaluates to "5".

Comment: In the code definition, it looks like this:

Comment: That is the correct value. Have you tried just entering 5 instead of CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate in the GetFilesAsync method?

Comment: //
        // Summary:
        //     A deep, flat list sorted by System.ItemDate. You can use this option only
        //     for folders in a library or the HomeGroup folder. System.ItemDate is a computed
        //     property that changes based on the content type; for example, it maps to
        //     System.Photo.DateTaken for photos.
        [SupportedOn(100794368, Platform.Windows)]
        [SupportedOn(100794368, Platform.WindowsPhone)]
        OrderByDate = 5,

Comment: Yes, I tried that just now, and it makes no difference. Same "Out of Range" exception occurs.

Comment: I'm trying the same code in RT environment it gives me System.NotImplementedException in both the videos and photos. But I noticed something the based on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207995?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) windows phone 8.1 does not support queryoption is it true?